# Exception due to insert query taking a long time

Tags: postgresql

I am Using the below mentioned query for insert operation and sometimes when the data is large it's taking long time for execution because of which I am getting exception error.I want to know how can I reduce the execution time for insert query for large data.

```
@"DO $$
DECLARE maxversionnumber integer;
BEGIN
    select max(versionnumber) into maxversionnumber from reissue.holdingsclose;
    IF maxversionnumber IS  NULL THEN
                select 1 into maxversionnumber;
    ELSE
                        select max(versionnumber)+1 into maxversionnumber from reissue.holdingsclose;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO reissue.holdingsclose (feedid,
        filename,
        asofdate,
        returntypeid,
        currencyid,
        securityid,
        indexid,
        indexname,
        securitycode,
        sizemarkercode,
        icbclassificationkey,
        rgsclassificationkey,
        securitycountry,
        securitycurrency,
        pricecurrency,
        sizemarkerkey,
        startmarketcap,
        closemarketcap,
        marketcapbeforeinvestability,
        marketcapafterinvestability,
        adjustmentfactor,
        marketcapafteradjustmentfactor,
        grossmarketcap,
        netmarketcap,
        xddividendmarketcap,
        xddividendnetmarketcap,
        openprice,
        closeprice,
        shares,
        sharechg,
        investabilityweight,
        dividendyield,
        pctindexweight,
        growthfactor,
        valuefactor,
        marketcapgrowthfactor,
        marketcapvaluefactor,
        dailypriceperformance,
        dailytotalperformance,
        dailynetperformance,
        insertiontime,
        classificationnareitkey,
        classificationnomurakey,
        growthshares,
        valueshares,
        smid,
        meena,
        eurozone150flag,
        euro40,
        paneurope60,
        top100flag,
        top200flag,
        r2500,
        developedemerging,
        europe,
        europeexuk,
        frontier,
        g123,
        gccflag,
        gicsindustry,
        methodologycode,
        createdate,
        createuserid,
        modifieduser,
        modifieddate,
        reissueflag,
        productcode,versionnumber)
        SELECT feedid,
        filename,
        asofdate,
        returntypeid,
        currencyid,
        securityid,
        indexid,
        indexname,
        securitycode,
        sizemarkercode,
        icbclassificationkey,
        rgsclassificationkey,
        securitycountry,
        securitycurrency,
        pricecurrency,
        sizemarkerkey,
        startmarketcap,
        closemarketcap,
        marketcapbeforeinvestability,
        marketcapafterinvestability,
        adjustmentfactor,
        marketcapafteradjustmentfactor,
        grossmarketcap,
        netmarketcap,
        xddividendmarketcap,
        xddividendnetmarketcap,
        openprice,
        closeprice,
        shares,
        sharechg,
        investabilityweight,
        dividendyield,
        pctindexweight,
        growthfactor,
        valuefactor,
        marketcapgrowthfactor,
        marketcapvaluefactor,
        dailypriceperformance,
        dailytotalperformance,
        dailynetperformance,
        insertiontime,
        classificationnareitkey,
        classificationnomurakey,
        growthshares,
        valueshares,
        smid,
        meena,
        eurozone150flag,
        euro40,
        paneurope60,
        top100flag,
        top200flag,
        r2500,
        developedemerging,
        europe,
        europeexuk,
        frontier,
        g123,
        gccflag,
        gicsindustry,
        methodologycode,
        createdate,
        createuserid,
        modifieduser,
        modifieddate,
        reissueflag,
        productcode
        ,maxversionnumber as versionnumber
    FROM fct.holdingsclose  
    WHERE feedid =" + feedId + " ;" +
    "DELETE FROM fct.holdingsclose WHERE feedid =" + feedId + " ;" + "END $$;";
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I am getting inner exception message: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Comment: Is there an index on `fct.holdingsclose (feedid)`? If not, try to create one.

Comment: `select max(versionnumber)+1 into maxversionnumber` is a **really**, really bad way to generate unique IDs. Why aren't you using a sequence?

Comment: can you please guide how to use sequence as I am new so I don't know how to use that.

Comment: plus some times I am getting different exception also for UPSERT queries viz. InnerException = {"Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."}